# What are the common usage of Generics in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand what Typescript generics are commonly used for in real life case, not the niche cases. I understand that it adds an extra layer of abstraction to a function/class/interfaces so that they can be reused in different cases, but I feel like you can normally resort to using the unions and intersection types to accommodate a certain level of generality.

But, take the following example:

```js
interface Identities<V, W> {
   id1: V,
   id2: W
}

function identities<T, U> (arg1: T, arg2: U): Identities<T, U> {   
 let identities: Identities<T, U> = {
    id1: arg1,
    id2: arg2
  };
  return identities;
}
```

All this ensures that whatever types the arguments have, the return has to match the types.

I can imagine if you wanted your function/class to be able to accommodate a variety of different arguments, but your only constraint would be that they have to be compatible with certain methods:

```js
interface Lengthwise {
    length: number;
}

function loggingIdentity<T extends Lengthwise>(arg: T): T {
    console.log(arg.length);  // Now we know it has a .length property, so no more error
    return arg;
}
```

this being used in certain situations.

Comment: Are you looking for an example? One common example is. for React, when we define interfaces/type aliases as the generic types for the components.

Comment: It's useful when you're creating frameworks, for example like what @wentjun mentioned.

Also, it's useful when you're trying to define your own array function, for example merge sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "computer science" term for *Generics* is *Parametric Polymorphism*, and it actually demonstrates quite well what they are useful for. (Well, if you know what it means.)

So, what *does* it mean?

Well, let's just look at what "parametric" means in general. It just means that we can have parameters. I think we all can agree that parameters are useful. A function that can only add 3 and 5 is pretty boring. A function that can add any number to any number and can be parameterized over those numbers, now that is much more useful!

A *type constructor* (that's what a generic type is called in computer science) constructs a type from a another type. The name "type constructor" was chosen because in some branches of mathematics, functions are actually called "constructors" or "value constructors" (because they construct new output values based on input values), and a type constructor is very similar, except not at the value level but at the *type level*.

For example, the `Promise` type constructor takes one argument, let's say `number` and constructs from that a *new type*, which is a "NumberPromise".

So, the reason why type constructors with parameters are useful on the type level is the same reason why functions with parameters are useful on the value level: they allow you to construct new things out of existing things.

And why is *parametric polymorphism*, in particular, useful? I.e. polymorphism where the type parameter is completely unknown?

Remember what *polymorphism* means in general: a piece of code being able to do things with different types.

The most well-known form of polymorphism is *ad-hoc polymorphism*, where the code does *different things for each type* and must have a specific, separate implementation for every type it wants deal with. The most widely-used implementation of ad-hoc polymorphism is object-oriented virtual method dispatch, where each class has its own independent implementation of the method.

(In reality, OOP typically uses a combination of *subtype polymorphism* and ad-hoc polymorphism. Also, it supports *differential code-reuse* where the implementation of a subtype only needs to implement what it wants to do *differently* but can re-use the supertype's implementation e.g. via inheritance or prototype delegation.)

In parametric polymorphism, OTOH, there is only a *single operation* which works for *all types*. The typical beginner example is a function that returns the length of a singly-linked list. It doesn't actually need to know about the type of the elements, so it can be *parametric* in the element type, something like this:

```js
function length<T>(list: List<T>) {
  return list.rest === undefined ? 0 : 1 + length(list.rest);
}
```

This function does not do anything with the elements of the list, so it can be *generic* over the element type.

Another example is the *identity function*:

```js
function id<T>(it: T) {
  return it;
}
```

These functions are all *fully parametric*, i.e. they work for *any* type argument that you put in. In fact, they don't even care about the type at all.

There are, however, functions that need to know something about the types. For example, a `sort` function for lists needs to know that the elements are comparable. We need to put certain "bounds" around the type parameters, this is called *bounded polymorphism*:

```js
interface Comparable<T> {
  const enum Comparing {
    LessThan = -1,
    Equal,
    GreaterThan
  }

  compareTo(other: T): Comparing
}

function sort<T extends Comparable<T>>(list: List<T>) {
  // do some sorting
}
```

Regarding your question about modeling these with union and intersection types, the fundamental difference here is that with *parametric polymorphism*, the type is an *argument* that is supplied by the *user*. If you wanted to e.g. model a generic collection class by using a union of all possible element types, you would have to know *every possible element type that may ever be written by anybody on the planet* in advance, before you write the collection! That is clearly not possible. You will never be able to list out every possible type that can be put in a list or a map or an array.

Or, think of function types: it would be very restrictive if functions only worked with a specific exhaustive union of types that the TypeScript designers put into the definition, don't you think?

Here is a link to a question Software Engineering that illuminates some aspects from a different direction. The OP asked in the context of C#, which is more restrictive than TypeScript in that it doesn't support union or intersection types, but I think the discussion will still be useful for you:

- [Generics vs common interface](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/303289/1352): Are generics useful for anything other than collections, and why can't I just declare my collections to contain instances of a single general type?

Answer (score 1):

Generics can be used to store additional Data from API-calls for example:

API-Response:

```
value: {} // this is generic
messages: [] // additional logging/errors/warnings
// other properties that apply for all objects
```

Typescript:

```
export interface GenericResponse<T> {
  value: T;
  messages: ApiMessageItem[];
 // additional properties
}
```

where T is whatever Object I called from my API.

You could still do this with Unions, but i think its cleaner to use generics, espescially with 50 different API Objects.

Comment: I'm new to typescript so could you explain how this T would be different from `any` then?

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=97&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgcWCTQWwCVgBnSJS4AHgBUA+OAbwCg44A3TAGwCuwAFxxGAbi5wAtlUqYA5lQD8YyjCjJFAbQC6UuAHojcTABNzCGAghIBcMFAhg0NqhwC+HDqEixEFDQsXDgAQSQATwpqOzp2aT4hUTMow1l5JVV1TW19QxMzS2tbe35HZ1dYBA9vDmw4+AgAIwArMUJiLXIqGjp6JEEZZrRWAF52XgFhMQAmOG8G2ia22Y6iEh7Y2gZB4dG4CbYp5LEAclmzhZ8ljTgW1oBmMQjo3ri8I5OZyahMJHMEBkAAVKm5Iuc-gCgQBlXJIRRXTwLYymJLCODYf5wEapSIwAAW2h8HCAA) clarifies what I mean. Basically dont use any, unless you really cant be sure of the type (in that case, consider unknown and unions first).

Comment: so generics is more like determining what the type of arguments will be at the time of invocation of a function, as opposed to having them pre-determined?

Comment: There is certainly a lot more to generics than that, but yes you can use them for that. Consider giving https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html a read for some more information on typescript generics.